# Maven fails to find Jive archetypes from repository when building initial jive project

Tags: maven

I'm trying to follow the instructions as specified here: https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-3544

For some reason when I execute:

```
mvn archetype:generate -e -B -DarchetypeGroupId=com.jivesoftware.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-jive-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=6.0.x-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.jivesoftware.dummycustomer -DartifactId=dummyCustomerSite
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find the archetype.

I believe I've added all the changes I needed to my ~/.m2/settings.xml (i.e. proxy settings,  profile, and jive credentials)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jive.archiva</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>jive.internal</id>
                <name>Jive's Repository</name>
                <url>https://maven-secure.jivesoftware.com/archiva/repository/jive.internal</url>
            </repository>

            <repository>
                <id>jive.snapshots</id>
                <name>Jive's Repository</name>
                <url>https://maven-secure.jivesoftware.com/archiva/repository/jive.snapshots</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>jive.internal</id>
                <name>Jive's Repository</name>
                <url>https://maven-secure.jivesoftware.com/archiva/repository/jive.internal</url>
            </pluginRepository>

            <pluginRepository>
                <id>jive.snapshots</id>
                <name>Jive's Repository</name>
                <url>https://maven-secure.jivesoftware.com/archiva/repository/jive.snapshots</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

        <properties>
            <tomcat6.home><![CDATA[/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.36]]></tomcat6.home>
            <cargo.wait>false</cargo.wait>
            <jive.setup>true</jive.setup>
            <jive.devMode>true</jive.devMode>
            <pluginDirs>null</pluginDirs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<servers>
 <server>
    <id>jive.internal</id>
    <username>john.smith</username>
    <password>password123</password>
 </server>
 <server>
    <id>jive.snapshots</id>
    <username>john.smith</username>
    <password>password123</password>
 </server>
 <server>
    <id>central</id>
    <username>john.smith</username>
    <password>password123</password>
 </server>
```

```
       
        
         true
         http
         proxy.mycompany.com
         8080
         *.mycompany.com|localhost
        
       
     
```
When running, Maven says it can't find the file:

```
$mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=com.jivesoftware.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-jive-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=5.0.x-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.cirrus.jive -DartifactId=tap
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:create (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[WARNING] This goal is deprecated. Please use mvn archetype:generate instead
[INFO] Defaulting package to group ID: com.cirrus.jive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.116s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 11 16:17:50 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error creating from archetype: org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DownloadNotFoundException: Requested com.jivesoftware.maven:maven-jive-archetype:jar:5.0.x-SNAPSHOT download does not exist. Could not find artifact com.jivesoftware.maven:maven-jive-archetype:jar:5.0.x-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.jivesoftware.maven -DartifactId=maven-jive-archetype -Dversion=5.0.x-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.jivesoftware.maven -DartifactId=maven-jive-archetype -Dversion=5.0.x-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] com.jivesoftware.maven:maven-jive-archetype:jar:5.0.x-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

EDIT: After following Charlee's suggesions, I get these warnings.

```
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jivesoftware/maven/maven-jive-archetype/6.0.x-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jivesoftware/maven/maven-jive-archetype/6.0.x-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
...
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.245s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 12 10:03:30 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It looks like it still can't find the archetype, and then goes to another repository so this isn't exactly what I want.
If I change the argument for archetype version to 5.0 (which I think what my company might want me to use). Setting DarchetypeVersion=5.0.x-SNAPSHOT gives me this (note where it says xxxx actually should say http because stackoverflow is complaining that I can't post html links due to lack of my reputation):

```
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: xxxx://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jivesoftware/maven/maven-jive-archetype/5.0.x-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.009s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 12 10:08:44 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.jivesoftware.maven:maven-jive-archetype:5.0.x-SNAPSHOT) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.jivesoftware.maven:maven-jive-archetype:5.0.x-SNAPSHOT)
```

Any advice as to why I can't seem to find the 5.0.x- snapshot?

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow so I wasn't sure how. Here it is:

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  You can go to those repository URLs in your web browser and manually confirm that things look right.  For example, this is the Maven Central URL for net.sourceforge.pldoc:pldoc:1.3.9 http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/pldoc/pldoc/1.3.9/

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know how to find the Maven Central URLs for Jive like how you did for pldoc?

Comment: No, I believe Jive's repository is private (which is why you've got a password from them).  What I was showing you is that you can (probably) browse the remote Maven repo with your web browser and use that to verify what's happening (I can't, since I don't have the password).  Try going to https://maven-secure.jivesoftware.com/archiva/repository/jive.internal and browse around.  See if you can find `com/jivesoftware/maven/maven-jive-archetype/`.  It may be that the version number you're using is wrong?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot, I went to https://maven-secure.jivesoftware.com/archiva/repository/jive.internal/com/jivesoftware/jive/ and I saw this:
http://imgur.com/Txldp6j

Do you see anything strange going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Since the profile named `jive.archiva` is not active by default. AFAIK, there are 2 possible ways as the following :-

1.Execute the maven by specifying the profile id.

```bsh
mvn archetype:generate -e -B 
   -P jive.archiva 
   -DarchetypeGroupId=com.jivesoftware.maven 
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-jive-archetype 
   -DarchetypeVersion=6.0.x-SNAPSHOT 
   -DgroupId=com.jivesoftware.dummycustomer 
   -DartifactId=dummyCustomerSite
```

2.Make the profile active by missing some system property.

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jive.archiva</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <property>
               <name>!disableJive</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profile>
```

You may wondered why we not use the `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>`. Here may be the answer

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds **unless another profile in the same POM is activated** using one of the previously described methods.**All profiles that are active by default are *automatically deactivated*** when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config.

Please see further information at [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

I hope this may help.

Comment: Hi Charlee, thanks for your help. Doing what you told me I get this:

Comment: What does you get? Please provide us the result.

Comment: Hi Charlee, I've edited my original post doing what you've told me to. For some reason I still can't get snapshots for 5.0.x, and for 6.0.x i works but it doesn't seem to be going to the Jive repository and instead falling back to the maven repository.